# How can I change a URL that an application pings

Tags: macos

I'm trying to resurrect an old mac application.

Currently it is trying to scrape data from `deadurl.com/?12345`

Although that url is dead so it's not working. There are other url's which provide the same data and are still alive such as

`differentWorkingUrl.com/?12345`

Is there a way I can decompile the application and replace the scraping URL?

Comment: Installing [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/index.html) and creating a reverse proxy may work...

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to is first find the IP address of the website which has the data you need. Enter this command in Terminal (only the dot-delimited portions, no slashes or anything):

```
nslookup deadurl.com
```

You should get a non-authoritative answer. This is what you want. Copy that address, and then enter this command into Terminal:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

You'll have to enter your password and press return to proceed. Note, for security, it won't show as you type. Once you're in the host file, move the cursor down to the bottom by pushing the function key, and the down arrow. Then press the "o" key, and paste the IP address, press tab, and type workingurl.com, replacing workingurl.com with your working URL.

Now press escape, ":", "x", return.

Now, assuming the software doesn't circumvent the hosts file in some way, it should have its communications redirected to the working URL, assuming the URL's path hasn't changed beyond the domain name.

Comment: If it is in the binary this is your only hope ... note that this will not work with https as the certificate is not going to be match (if they even check it)... and it will only work if the links are EXACTLY the same except for the domain name (there are workaround, but idk setting up a proxy server in the middle sounds too much of a hassle)

Comment: Depending on how the program is accessing the data, I know a few geeky ways to redirect access to any URL you want, but they're not easy. I'm hoping this works. If not, I'll have to ask for more info.

Comment: Huh... looking at this now, I actually did this backwards. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

It likely depends on where `deadurl` is stored.

If it's in the compiled binary, then no.
If it's in some support document, then possibly.

I'd start by getting [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware)
Launch it, drag your App to it, which will set the search location, then on the left set
File Contents
All Words
Ignore Case
Package Contents
Invisible Files & Folders.

Then type `deadurl` in the search bar & hit the 'go' icon on the right.

See what it finds.

If it finds an editable, non-binary document, then you have a chance.

Comment: It is a binary unfortunately. Is there no 'hacking' program I can use to edit it possibly?